# Cucumber Scenario Outline Step Definitions

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

I've run into a wall when attempting to write my first step defs for a Scenario Outline in Cucumber.

I am using Gherkin features in Cucumber where my step defs are calling my various page classes which will drive and check the page using Selenium. This framework is in Java.

I have got through my scenarios OK so far but I now have a feature which looks a bit like the following:

```
Given I have started a policy amendment request application
When I <Colour> selected a Colour
And I <Number> select a Number
Then I <Date> be expected to populate a date the change is effective from

      Examples:
        |Colour    | Number | Date      |
        |Have      | Donot  | Will      |
        |Havenot   | Do     | Willnot   |
```

The question I have here is around how this is handled at step Def. If I look at the step
`When I <Colour> selected a Colour`
then I know that I can add a step def as follows to pick up this line

```
@When("^I \"([^\"]*)\" selected a Colour$")
public void iColourSelectedA(String colour) throws Throwable
```

But this will pass in a string of "Have" and "Have not". I am wanting each input from this step to drive drive my application differently. So I'm wondering how best to do handle this.

The code I want to drive execute is:

```
objPolicyAmendRequest.setColour();
```

So in one instance (when passed in string = "Have") I want to pass in a value into my method such as objPolicyAmendRequest.setColour("Blue");

and the other (when passed in string = "Have not") I dont want to pass anything to this method.

I'm guessing I need to go down the line of an if statement but unsure if there is way Cucumber helps with this or not.

Hope I'm making sense. I'm still a bit new to programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your step for

```
@When("^I \"([^\"]*)\" selected a Colour$")
public void iColourSelectedA(String colour) throws Throwable
```

you can add a condition for the value color.

```
if(colour.equalsIgnoreCase("Have"){
  //Some Logic Here
} else {
  //Some Logic Here
}
```

you can also use `switch` if you are expecting different values for Colour

Comment: Great. I was thinking along these lines but wasn't sure if this was the right way to go so thanks for the reassurance.

Comment: Should you have the same step for stating you have **a** colour, and also stating that you have a **specific** colour?

Comment: The cucumber scenario is just badly written. I don't even understand the logic of the steps

Answer (score 0):

I would use this for specifying which colour you want to choose:

```
@When("^I select the colour \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void iSelectTheColour(String colour) throws Throwable
```

And this for (not) selecting a colour, not caring which colour it is (a default or random value):

```
@When("^I have(?: not|) selected a colour$")
public void iHaveSelectedAColour(String optionalNot) throws Throwable
```

Then in the code, you see whether the default value should be selected or not:

```
if(optionalNot.equals(" not"){
  //Some Logic Here
} else {
  //Some Logic Here
}
```

This means that your scenario works: have | have not, but as the wording needs to change, so does the functionality.

In all likelihood, I believe you could do something like this:

```
string colourToPick = //Some Colour;

if(optionalNot.equals(" not"){
  iSelectTheColour(someOtherColour);
} else {
  iSelectTheColour(colourToPick);
}
```